# How to add a SaveOrUpdateCopy event listener in NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, events, listener

How can I add a event listener for SaveOrUpdateCopy in NHibernate ?
I see that the ListenerType enumeration does not have a
'SaveOrUpdateCopy' type. I tried using the 'Merge' type, but that adds
it to the MergeEventListeners collection. The SaveOrUpdateCopy invokes
the events from the SaveOrUpdateCopyEventListeners collection.

How can I add my event class to the SaveOrUpdateCopyEventListeners
collection in NHibernate?

Answer (score 1):

On our project :

```
listeners.SaveOrUpdateEventListeners = new ISaveOrUpdateEventListener[] 
    { new TrackChangeFlushEntityEventListener(),
      new DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener() 
    };
```

works for SaveOrUpdateCopy